# Search for and sort values, return adjacent cells

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a large excel spreadsheet with several columns of information regarding events that have occurred for an event company, with details of each event in various columns.  (I only start with that because the columns I need to search/sort are not the leftmost column, so I don't believe I can use VLOOKUP for this).  I call this sheet DB (my abbreviation for "database")

In DB column G, I have a list of event locations that have been used over the past several years.

In DB Column H, I have a formula which searches column G, and returns the number of times each event location has been used.  If a location occurs only once, it obviously returns a 1 in column H.  If it occurs more than once, the first instance returns the number of occurrences, and other instances return a zero.  That way, I only have a non-zero number for each location once.

What I'd like to do on another sheet (in the same workbook) is make a dynamic list of the results of Column H in descending order, and next to that, show the matching event locations from Column G.  So in effect, I'd have a list of the most popular event locations, along with how often they've been used.  As I add to the DB spreadsheet, this list would automatically update itself.

I know that to "sort" the Column H numbers, I could easily use LARGE to find the largest number, then the next largest, then the next, etc.  But problem 1 is that if two event locations have been used the same number of times, this creates a problem for LARGE.  Problem 2 is that I can't figure a way to return the info from Column G next to these results.

Is this possible?  Or do I have to manually sort this info whenever I update the list?

Comment: You need a `Pivot Table`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jbarker2160 that a Pivot table is the way to go. However, if you really want a standard sheet, this should work for you.

I'm going to call your second sheet DB2. Let's say A1 has title Times Used and B1 has title Venue Name.
I'm also going to assume that DB has title headers as well.

On DB2 cell A2 enter the formula `=DB!H2`

On DB2 cell B2 enter the formula `=DB!G2`

Now, fill down both cells a really long way. It should be filled down to the max number of events, not the max number of venues. Go way past your current number of events so that you don't need to keep filling down later as you add more entries on DB. You'd only encounter problems when you add an event at a new venue, but it's still best to avoid these types of problems if you can.

Last, sort by column A, and filter out 0.